# Where do I put "platform: 'node'" in an Angular 17 app running on node 20?

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, angular-cli

**TL;DR**

I need to use `platform: 'node'` to allow an Angular app to find modules that are no longer bundled with WebPack 5, but are bundled with node.  But I've been unable to find the file the platform setting needs to go in.

Can someone please tell me where the platform setting needs to go?  Please?

**Slightly More Info**

I used Angular CLI 17.0.0 to create an Angular app that's running on node 20.9.0.  When I try to "ng serve" I see messages like the following:

> The package "stream" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node.
> Are you trying to bundle for node? You can use "platform: 'node'" to do that,
> which will remove this error.

Can anyone tell me what file `platform: 'node'` should go in?  I haven't been able to find "platform" assigned any value in a .json or .config.js file.

Comment: Are importing stream somewhere ?

Comment: I also have this error, but only when running yarn build command

Comment: Matthieu  -- I'm not importing stream.  There are only 30 packages listed as dependencies in my package.json file, but at least one of the 1000+ packages that were installed by npm is trying to import stream.

Comment: I've found that @microsoft/signalr version 8.0.0 was the problem for me. I downgraded to @microsoft/signalr version 7 and that fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

If you are using esbuild then the code change is like this:

```
import esbuild from 'esbuild'
await esbuild.build({
  platform: 'node'
})
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the name of the file that needs this code change?